# Render a partial after submit_tag is clicked in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I understand how to render a partial when clicking a normal link, simply use :remote, however I am having trouble rendering a partial when my search form is submitted via the submit_tag.

This is my code in index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(transports_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form" ) do %>

<%= select_tag "searchfrom", options_for_select(airport_names, params[:searchfrom]), :prompt => "Select From" %>
<%= select_tag "searchto", options_for_select(airport_names, params[:searchto]), :prompt => "Select To" %>

<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => 'transports/transports' %>
```

I want to render the transports/transports partial after the submit_tag is clicked, and I also don't want to transform it into a link_to link.

Comment: if you know how to render a partial with `link_to` using `remote: true` then you can do the same with a form as well. Just add `remote: true` to your `form_tag`. **Example:**   `<%= form_tag transports_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", remote: true do %>`

Comment: What @dkp explanation is correct, but looking from your code, you should do a `POST` method form, then from controller return an ajax javascript just to change the partial content (and/or) remove the form or whatever

Comment: @ksugiarto I am requesting directly from the database. `@transports = Transport.where("strtloc LIKE ? AND endloc LIKE ?", "#{params[:searchfrom]}%", "#{params[:searchto]}%")` This is what does the search from my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allow me to explain on the answer section since it is probably not too short.

Correct, when submit from form you send those `searchfrom` and `searchto` params to controller right to be query ingredients. Then return in `js` format from **Controller**, something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Then add create new type of return file like **create.js.erb**, contain something like:

```
$("#transports_list ").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'transports/transports') %>");
```

But please correct me, so long when my last RoR coding :P

*This method is so old, but more or less the concept can fulfilling your question, this [blog](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy) may help you to understand what I thought.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what finally worked for me. What I also added was the `remote: true` to the `form_tag` and it worked like a charm! Thank you. This also got rid of the ugly search query in my URL. This is why I love RoR.

Comment: Yes it is, I don't know how much it helps you, but good to hear, if you find your answer is much different from mine, you can always answer it yourself so people can look and learn from it :)